¿En qué parte de mi archivo HTML corresponde agregar un metadato, cuando intento agregar un conjunto de caracteres a mi archivo JS?
Intento agregar un conjunto de caracteres a mi archivo JS. ¿En qué parte de mi archivo HTML corresponde agregar un metadato?
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;"charset="UTF-8"/>


Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Bienvenida a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio. Un saludo.

el metadato que estas intentando agregar en tu archivo HTML es para especificar el conjunto de caracteres (charset), debes ponerlo dentro de la sección  del tu archivo por ejemplo:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;"charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>


Para cargar un archivo de javascript que tiene un conjunto de caracteres específico o diferente del de la página en sí, puedes indicar el charset en la etiqueta <script> con la que lo cargas, por ejemplo:
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="xyz.js"></script>

